# Unable to read NSNumber correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnumber

I'm trying to read back two `NSNumber` values that I've written to `NSUserDefaults` (`24` and `39993`). I can write the values just fine, but reading it back gives completely different values than expected. If the `NSNumber` was able to be read correctly I wanted to then convert it into a `UInt32` as it was originally.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self writeDefaults];
    [self readDefaults];
}

- (void)writeDefaults {

    UInt32 val1 = 24;
    UInt32 val2 = 39993;

    NSNumber* value1 = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:val1];
    NSNumber* value2 = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:val2];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:value1 forKey:@"value1"]; // saves 24
    [defaults setObject:value2 forKey:@"value2"]; // saves 39993

    NSLog(@"value1: %@",value1); // outputs 24
    NSLog(@"value2: %@",value2); // outputs 39993

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)readDefaults {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSNumber *val1 = [defaults valueForKey:@"value1"];
    NSNumber *val2 = [defaults valueForKey:@"value2"];

    NSLog(@"val1: %u",(unsigned int)val1); // outputs 6199
    NSLog(@"val2: %u",(unsigned int)val2); // outputs 10238263
}
@end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong on the `readDefaults` portion? thanks.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, The question you linked really does not look the same at all.

Comment: It's the exact same  fundamental problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, When I searched that answer never came up - so maybe the parameters of the search algorithm need a fundamental refurbishing.

Comment: Also just wanted to add that the "duplicate" question offers nothing in terms of an explanation as to why the behavior occurs, even though it's answered by vikingosegundo also. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the pointer memory addresses of the NSNumber objects

do

```
NSLog(@"val1: %lu",[val1 unsignedIntegerValue]);
NSLog(@"val2: %lu",[val2 unsignedIntegerValue]);
```

or stay in the object world

```
NSLog(@"val1: %@",val1);
NSLog(@"val2: %@",val2);
```